# How to return a static response in kong api-gateway

Tags: swagger, api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin, oas

I am using kong API-gateway in its DB-Less mode

as a result, I have a kong.yaml file as below:

```
_format_version: "2.1"
_transform: true

services:
  - name: service1
    url: http://service1:port/sample-path
    routes:
      - name: service1
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /service1/sample-path
        strip_path: true
```

As you see, the api-gateway dispatches requests from `/service1/sample-path` endpoint of api-gatway to `http://service1:port/sample-path`

I am looking for a way to add a new service such that when a request is sent to `/oas` endpoint of api-gateway, it loads a yaml or json file and return that as the response.

In action, I am looking for a way to return a static response instead of dispatching the request?

Any idea how to do this?

**pseudo code**

```
_format_version: "2.1"
_transform: true

services:
  - name: service1
    url: http://service1:port/sample-path
    routes:
      - name: service1
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /service1/sample-path
        strip_path: true
  - name: oas
    url: STATIC YAML OR JSON FILE
    routes:
      - name: oas
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /oas
        strip_path: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that with the plugin https://github.com/IntelliGrape/kong-plugin-static-response

Comment: I did not find it on the kong hub.